# Creating a binary dependant on Qt 5

Tags: qt, package, version

I created a development environment with Fedora 18 and Qt 5

When I compile my app it will be 64 bit, and depend on Qt 5.  After some research it seems that will be a problem since Centos 6.x is still dependong on Qt 4.6, and Centos 5.x is dependant on earlier Qt, and I'm guessin Ubuntu has its own package limitations.

Is there a "safe" version of Qt I can compile against to ensure it runs everywhere?  If not, how can I expect customers to run my program?

Comment: Is your software free software or not? Free software: Try openSUSE. If proprietary: Try linking statically, or limit the number of supported target platforms, if that's feasible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target Linux, then I would recommend using Qt 4.8 (available on most of the Linux Distros), forget about Qt 5 for a year or so. Hardly any Linux distro other than Ubuntu 13.04 and above comes with Qt 5.

Secondly, as far as compiling is considered, if you wish to target Linux distros other than Ubuntu and Fedora than never use Ubuntu or Fedora for compilation. These are bleeding edge Linux distros which include new libraries without much testing. You will not only face the problem of old Qt versions in some Linux distros as you will face the bigger problem of glibc (C library). Make sure the Linux distro you use for compilation has a minimum possible glibc version for Qt 4.8, otherwise even if any Linux distro has Qt 4.8 installed, but has a lower version of glibc, you app still won't run. You can check out [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com) to find out glibc and Qt versions for any Linux Distro

**Example:**

I compiled my app on Ubuntu 12.04, Qt 4.8.1 with glibc v 2.16 (perhaps). I got a bug report than application does not run on CrunchBang which also has Qt 4.8.1 available but since it is a Debian unstable Linux Distro it uses glibc v2.13. Since that day I always compile my application on CrunchBang (very lighweight, you can Virtual Box for this) and hardly some one complains now.

As far as CentOs is considered, you will need to recompile your code on CentOS.

Comment: I've been building using QT 5.1 and have a lot of code written now.  It looks like over time the syntax has changed for signals, connect, and probably more.  Is Qt 4.8.1 compatible with the Qt 5.x syntax?

Comment: Also, since my app targets linux servers, I suspect RH/Centos will be the most popular distro.  Why would a crunchbang compilation not run under RH/centos?  And to take that another step, how many VM's do you run so that you can compile for major distros, architectures, etc.?

Comment: @Michelle Yes Qt 4.8 is compatible with Qt 5 but you will need some if defs very few. As far as connect is concerned Qt 5 supports both old style and new style. You should use old style for compatibility, you need two Linux distributions for compilation 64 and 32 bit. Check out version of glibc for Centos, if it is more than 2.12 than crunchbang compilation will work on centos